# Examples using CastCompanionLibrary to simply display an image

Tags: android, google-cast

I am looking for and example of casting an image to chromecast in android. Oddly enough it doesn't seem like this is covered in the googlecast sample repositories. Does anyone have a simple implementation of this? I basically would like to click on an image in my app's photo gallery on my android device and have it cast to the screen. 
One side question is, does the image need to be at a url? or is it possible to stream the image to the device? I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: I believe it would have to be at a URL

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this without the CastCompanionLibrary, but based on google's [CastHelloText-android](https://github.com/googlecast) sample. Basically what I did was:

1. encode an image into a base64 string and send it as a message to a custom receiver
2. modify the sample's receiver to receive a base64 string and set it as the image source.
3. [upload and register](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration#RegisterApp) my receiver and have the application use the generated application id

This is the code for the receiver:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      img#androidImage {
        height:auto;
        width:100%;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Cast Hello Text</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="androidImage" src="" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(0);
        window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
        console.log('Starting Receiver Manager');

        // handler for the 'ready' event
        castReceiverManager.onReady = function(event) {
          console.log('Received Ready event: ' + JSON.stringify(event.data));
          window.castReceiverManager.setApplicationState("Application status is ready...");
        };

        // handler for 'senderconnected' event
        castReceiverManager.onSenderConnected = function(event) {
          console.log('Received Sender Connected event: ' + event.data);
          console.log(window.castReceiverManager.getSender(event.data).userAgent);
        };

        // handler for 'senderdisconnected' event
        castReceiverManager.onSenderDisconnected = function(event) {
          console.log('Received Sender Disconnected event: ' + event.data);
          if (window.castReceiverManager.getSenders().length == 0) {
            window.close();
          }
        };

        // handler for 'systemvolumechanged' event
        castReceiverManager.onSystemVolumeChanged = function(event) {
          console.log('Received System Volume Changed event: ' + event.data['level'] + ' ' +
              event.data['muted']);
        };

        // create a CastMessageBus to handle messages for a custom namespace
        window.messageBus =
          window.castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus(
              'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.helloworld');

        // handler for the CastMessageBus message event
        window.messageBus.onMessage = function(event) {
          console.log('Message recieved');

          var obj = JSON.parse(event.data)

          console.log('Message type: ' + obj.type);
          if (obj.type == "text") {
            console.log('Skipping message: ' + obj.data);
          }

          if (obj.type == "image") {
            var source = 'data:image/png;base64,'.concat(obj.data)
            displayImage(source);
          }

          // inform all senders on the CastMessageBus of the incoming message event
          // sender message listener will be invoked
          window.messageBus.send(event.senderId, event.data);
        }

        // initialize the CastReceiverManager with an application status message
        window.castReceiverManager.start({statusText: "Application is starting"});
        console.log('Receiver Manager started');
      };


      function displayImage(source) {
        console.log('received image');
        document.getElementById("androidImage").src=source;
        window.castReceiverManager.setApplicationState('image source changed');
      };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the modified MainActivity.java code. Don't forget to modify the app_id in string.xml once your receiver application is registered.

2 notes:

- The sent messages are wrapped in a JSON object so I can filter out
  the text messages.
- The ENCODED_IMAGE_STRING variable isn't defined in this
  example, you'll have to find an image and convert it to a base64 string yourself.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.casthelloworld;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.cast.ApplicationMetadata;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.Cast;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.Cast.MessageReceivedCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastDevice;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastMediaControlIntent;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
/**
 * Main activity to send messages to the receiver.
 */
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private MediaRouter mMediaRouter;
    private MediaRouteSelector mMediaRouteSelector;
    private MediaRouter.Callback mMediaRouterCallback;
    private CastDevice mSelectedDevice;
    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
    private Cast.Listener mCastListener;
    private ConnectionCallbacks mConnectionCallbacks;
    private ConnectionFailedListener mConnectionFailedListener;
    private HelloWorldChannel mHelloWorldChannel;
    private boolean mApplicationStarted;
    private boolean mWaitingForReconnect;
    private String mSessionId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
                android.R.color.transparent));

        // When the user clicks on the button, use Android voice recognition to
        // get text
        Button voiceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.voiceButton);
        voiceButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
            }
        });


        // When the user clicks on the button, use Android voice recognition to
        // get text
        Button yarrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tmpButton);
        yarrButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                castImage();
            }
        });

        // Configure Cast device discovery
        mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
                .addControlCategory(
                        CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(getResources()
                                .getString(R.string.app_id))).build();
        mMediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback();
    }

    private void castImage()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "castImage()");

        String image_string = createJsonMessage(MessageType.image, ENCODED_IMAGE_STRING);

        sendMessage(image_string);
    }

    /**
     * Android voice recognition
     */
    private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                getString(R.string.message_to_cast));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /*
     * Handle the voice recognition response
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onActivityResult(int, int,
     * android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            if (matches.size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, matches.get(0));
                String message = createJsonMessage(MessageType.text, matches.get(0));
                sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Start media router discovery
        mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
                MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // End media router discovery
            mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        teardown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
        MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat
                .getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
        // Set the MediaRouteActionProvider selector for device discovery.
        mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Callback for MediaRouter events
     */
    private class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {

        @Override
        public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo info) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRouteSelected");
            // Handle the user route selection.
            mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(info.getExtras());

            launchReceiver();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo info) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRouteUnselected: info=" + info);
            teardown();
            mSelectedDevice = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start the receiver app
     */
    private void launchReceiver() {
        try {
            mCastListener = new Cast.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void onApplicationDisconnected(int errorCode) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "application has stopped");
                    teardown();
                }

            };
            // Connect to Google Play services
            mConnectionCallbacks = new ConnectionCallbacks();
            mConnectionFailedListener = new ConnectionFailedListener();
            Cast.CastOptions.Builder apiOptionsBuilder = Cast.CastOptions
                    .builder(mSelectedDevice, mCastListener);
            mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mConnectionFailedListener)
                    .build();

            mApiClient.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed launchReceiver", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Google Play services callbacks
     */
    private class ConnectionCallbacks implements
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");

            if (mApiClient == null) {
                // We got disconnected while this runnable was pending
                // execution.
                return;
            }

            try {
                if (mWaitingForReconnect) {
                    mWaitingForReconnect = false;

                    // Check if the receiver app is still running
                    if ((connectionHint != null)
                            && connectionHint
                                    .getBoolean(Cast.EXTRA_APP_NO_LONGER_RUNNING)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "App  is no longer running");
                        teardown();
                    } else {
                        // Re-create the custom message channel
                        try {
                            Cast.CastApi.setMessageReceivedCallbacks(
                                    mApiClient,
                                    mHelloWorldChannel.getNamespace(),
                                    mHelloWorldChannel);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while creating channel", e);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Launch the receiver app
                    Cast.CastApi
                            .launchApplication(mApiClient,
                                    getString(R.string.app_id), false)
                            .setResultCallback(
                                    new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResult(
                                                ApplicationConnectionResult result) {
                                            Status status = result.getStatus();
                                            Log.d(TAG,
                                                    "ApplicationConnectionResultCallback.onResult: statusCode "
                                                            + status.getStatusCode());
                                            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                                ApplicationMetadata applicationMetadata = result
                                                        .getApplicationMetadata();
                                                mSessionId = result
                                                        .getSessionId();
                                                String applicationStatus = result
                                                        .getApplicationStatus();
                                                boolean wasLaunched = result
                                                        .getWasLaunched();
                                                Log.d(TAG,
                                                        "application name: "
                                                                + applicationMetadata
                                                                        .getName()
                                                                + ", status: "
                                                                + applicationStatus
                                                                + ", sessionId: "
                                                                + mSessionId
                                                                + ", wasLaunched: "
                                                                + wasLaunched);
                                                mApplicationStarted = true;

                                                // Create the custom message
                                                // channel
                                                mHelloWorldChannel = new HelloWorldChannel();
                                                try {
                                                    Cast.CastApi
                                                            .setMessageReceivedCallbacks(
                                                                    mApiClient,
                                                                    mHelloWorldChannel
                                                                            .getNamespace(),
                                                                    mHelloWorldChannel);
                                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                                    Log.e(TAG,
                                                            "Exception while creating channel",
                                                            e);
                                                }

                                                // set the initial instructions
                                                // on the receiver
                                                String message = createJsonMessage(MessageType.text, getString(R.string.instructions));
                                                sendMessage(message);
                                            } else {
                                                Log.e(TAG,
                                                        "application could not launch");
                                                teardown();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to launch application", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
            mWaitingForReconnect = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Google Play services callbacks
     */
    private class ConnectionFailedListener implements
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed ");

            teardown();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Tear down the connection to the receiver
     */
    private void teardown() {
        Log.d(TAG, "teardown");
        if (mApiClient != null) {
            if (mApplicationStarted) {
                if (mApiClient.isConnected()  || mApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    try {
                        Cast.CastApi.stopApplication(mApiClient, mSessionId);
                        if (mHelloWorldChannel != null) {
                            Cast.CastApi.removeMessageReceivedCallbacks(
                                    mApiClient,
                                    mHelloWorldChannel.getNamespace());
                            mHelloWorldChannel = null;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while removing channel", e);
                    }
                    mApiClient.disconnect();
                }
                mApplicationStarted = false;
            }
            mApiClient = null;
        }
        mSelectedDevice = null;
        mWaitingForReconnect = false;
        mSessionId = null;
    }

    /**
     * Send a text message to the receiver
     * 
     * @param message
     */
    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mApiClient != null && mHelloWorldChannel != null) {
            try {
                Cast.CastApi.sendMessage(mApiClient,
                        mHelloWorldChannel.getNamespace(), message)
                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Status result) {
                                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Sending message failed");
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception while sending message", e);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom message channel
     */
    class HelloWorldChannel implements MessageReceivedCallback {

        /**
         * @return custom namespace
         */
        public String getNamespace() {
            return getString(R.string.namespace);
        }

        /*
         * Receive message from the receiver app
         */
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(CastDevice castDevice, String namespace,
                String message) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + message);
        }

    }

    enum MessageType {
        text,
        image,
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        //Get the view's background
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null)
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        // draw the view on the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap;
    }

    private static String createJsonMessage(MessageType type, String message)
    {
        return String.format("{\"type\":\"%s\", \"data\":\"%s\"}", type.toString(), message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe steps of how do you upload custom receiver? I just created .js file and uploaded to Google Drive and made world visibility. After put link to Cast Console. And seems like Chromecast can't install this receiver after connecting with device.

Answer (score 3):

Since on Chromecast your application is running inside a web browser, you need to have an `<img/>` tag show the image. The `src` attribute of that tag should point to the image that you want to see and it has to be a url, so if your image is residing on your phone's local storage, you need to start a small web server in your mobile application to serve that image and communicate with the receiver what url it should point at (which would be the url at which your server is serving that image). these are all doable and you can use the CastCompanionLibrary, if you want, to communicate with your custom receiver; simply use the `DataCastManager` class instead of `VideoCastManager`.

Answer (score 2):

May be my answer will be helpful for other developers, because I also did'nt found good solution and done it by myself.

For showing image via Google Cast on your device screen from your app you can create and start simply web server from your app which will process http requests with selected image name or id in URL.

Example:

```
public class MyWebServer {

    private Activity activity;
    private static ServerSocket httpServerSocket;
    private static boolean isWebServerSunning;
    public static final String drawableDelimiter = "pic-"

    public MyWebServer(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void stopWebServer() {
        isWebServerSunning = false;
        try {
            if (httpServerSocket != null) {
                httpServerSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void startWebServer() {
        isWebServerSunning = true;
        Thread webServerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            Socket socket;
            HttpResponseThread httpResponseThread;
            try {
                httpServerSocket = new ServerSocket(5050);
                while (isWebServerSunning) {
                    socket = httpServerSocket.accept();
                    httpResponseThread = new HttpResponseThread(socket);
                    httpResponseThread.start();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        webServerThread.start();
    }

    private class HttpResponseThread extends Thread {

        Socket clientSocket;

        HttpResponseThread(Socket socket) {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                 OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            ) {

                String input = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if (input != null && !input.isEmpty() && input.contains("/") && input.contains(" ")) {

                    if (input.contains(drawableDelimiter)) {

                        String imageId = input.substring(input.indexOf("/") + 1, input.lastIndexOf(" ")).trim().split(drawableDelimiter)[1];

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), Integer.parseInt(imageId));
                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapBytes);

                            outputStream.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n".getBytes());
                            outputStream.write("Server: Apache/0.8.4\r\n".getBytes());
                            outputStream.write(("Content-Length: " + bitmapBytes.toByteArray().length + "\r\n").getBytes());
                            outputStream.write("\r\n".getBytes());
                            outputStream.write(bitmapBytes.toByteArray());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And just start or stop your web server at when Google Cast will be useable or stopped.

```
MyWebServer myWebServer = new MyWebServer(this); // pass your activity here
myWebServer.startWebServer();
myWebServer.stopWebServer();
```

Comment: How do I point the cast session to the local web server?

Comment: this solution only for embedded web server