# How to choose type of Receiver App for Chromecast application

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

I have an Image with 3840x2160px resolution which is identically maximum for 4K screens and I want to cast it on my TV screen through chromecast.

I have read plenty of solutions and documentation on Stackoverflow and developer.google but I couldn't identified the one what I need.

Looking in Here : [Cast Image to Chromecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643907/cast-image-photo-to-chromecast)

accepted answer says that one can **"simply send a url to the Chromecast device and grab it from your sever inside the receiver app. This the the recommended way to send photos across to the Chromecast"**

I will give it a try but **what should be the type for my receiver app when registering my cast application for above described scenario.**

1. Custom Receiver or 2. Styled Media Receiver.

Remote Display Receiver is not supported for Chrome so it is excluded from list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to show an image, Default/Styled receiver would do, no additional receiver work is needed. If you want to show a slide show with some more advanced features, then you need to write a custom receiver.

Comment: Great.. Thank You.. One last thing, am I able to send an image URL to chromcast device from chrome (Chromecast extension installed) without registering an app?

Comment: If you use the Default Receiver, then no registration is required

Comment: I am facing an issue again.. On the call of chrome.cast.requestSession() method the chrome should open the dialog box to choose device which is now leading to the failure callback. What should be the possible reason for this