# Send Base64 encoded image as string to Chromecast

Tags: javascript, android, chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

The problem is to send local image from phone as encoded Base64 string to Chromecast. And decode it using my Custom Receiver. I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121669/examples-using-castcompanionlibrary-to-simply-display-an-image) guide which is based on [this project sample](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android).

I suggest the problem might be in:

1. Custom Receiver is not proper (I'm not strong in JS).
2. Chromecast didn't load that Receiver (I don't know how to check that).
3. Image was encoded wrong on device or decoded on Chromecast.

You see, it seems like I coded everithing right since the **status of Chromecast** when I send photo is:

```
 statusCode 0 (success), 
 application name: Default Media Receiver, 
 status: Ready To Cast, 
 sessionId: 34D6CE75-4798-4294-BF45-2F4701CE4782, 
 wasLaunched: true.
```

**This is how I send image as String:**

```
mCastManager.castImage(mCastManager.getEncodedImage(currentEntryPictureByPoint.getPath()));
```

Methods used:

```
public void castImage(String encodedImage)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "castImage()");
    String image_string = createJsonMessage(MessageType.image, encodedImage);
    sendMessage(image_string);
}

private static String createJsonMessage(MessageType type, String message)
{
    return String.format("{\"type\":\"%s\", \"data\":\"%s\"}", type.toString(), message);
}

/**
 * Convert Image to encoded String
 * */
public String getEncodedImage(String path){
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
    byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();

    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return encodedImage;
}

/**
 * Send a text message to the receiver
 *
 * @param message
 */
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (mApiClient != null && mCustomImageChannel != null) {
        try {
            Cast.CastApi.sendMessage(mApiClient,
                    mCustomImageChannel.getNamespace(), message)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status result) {
                            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                //ALWAYS REACHING HERE :(
                                Log.e(TAG, "Sending message failed");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while sending message", e);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

If the sending process is correct then the Receiver is wrong and don't know how to decode this message properly. 
The way I **uploaded it** (well, at least I think that its uploaded...)

1. Registered new Custom Receiver on Google Cast Console and received Application ID.
2. Created cast_receiver.js file. The code inside this file is supposed to decode Base64 string into image.
3. Copied the code for Receiver from guide to .js file and changed NAMESPACE inside to my one: `urn:x-cast:com.it.innovations.smartbus`
4. Uploaded file on Google Drive and modified its access visibility to full public
5. Copied the [link to file](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0Bz2Lss3i7uJHZGRKLUx3amJLOTQ&export=download) to URL field in Cast Console. This link is direct download of file.
6. Restarted Chromecast. Seems like it tried to download something but not sure if succeed

If anyone faced this problem, please point me out what I am doing wrong. Appreciate any help.

*P.S. tell if some more code needed...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **very strongly** suggest to avoid using the `sendMessage()` for sending any large data set; those channels are meant to be used as control channels and not as a way to send a chunk of data. A much much simpler and more robust approach is to embed a tiny dumb web server in your local app (on the sender side) and "serve" your images to your chromecast. There is a number of ready-to-use embedded web servers that you can put in your app and requires almost no configuration; then you can serve all sorts of media, including images, to your chromecast with even the default or styled receiver.

Comment: Thanks for answer! What do you mean by "serve image to chromecast"? Some example could clarify that. If this a kind of alternative to `sendMessage()` I'd like to see how it works

Comment: You embed a web server in your phone application and set it up so that the media you are interested in is available through this embedded web server. Then you can create a regular MediaInfo and for its URL, you can point to the url that your web server has for your media (for example, a media item may be exposed through your embedded web server with a url like "http://192.168.1.101:8000/myImage.jpg" where 192.168.1.101 is the ip address of your phone on the wifi network of your home). Then chromecast can reach that content via that url like any other content on the internet.

Comment: In this case image will be send through Internet not the WiFi network, right? Chromecast basically will download instead of receiving, wouldn't it?

Comment: Your IP address is local for your phone on your wifi network so the packets won't leave your local wifi network.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will try this out and mark as answer if noone will sugest more simple solution

Comment: Woah! This approach seems to be working. The last question. How do I set time of casting the image? I need it to be on screen for 5 seconds.

Comment: If you want to do an accurate timing (and possibly some more sophisticated transitions, etc), you may need to write your own receiver.

Comment: How exactly should we send image? Currently I've used RemoteMediaPlayer which loads mediainfo with image url, but using media player doesn't seem correct. e.g. when I try to stop casting I see some sound controller which isn't needed in case of images. And I also think that it's not the best way of reaching my goal.